# DDL Database generation from XSD

Tags: .net, xml, entity-framework-core, xsd, ddl

I have been provided with an XSD and an XML file. I need to save the information on the XML file onto an SQL database which does not exist yet.

I've tried using tools like Altova XMLspy and XSD2DB to generate the database for insertion but these tools did not work due to the size and complexity of the schema.

The schema includes enumerators which are being interpreted as regular entities by these tools and are not being populated with the information that comes in the XSD.

I am using entity framework in .NET 6. Once approach I though about was generating entities classes from the XSD file and doing a code first database. The other option is to generate DDL statements from the XSD without using the tools I have already used.

If anyone could help me make me some progress as to what tools I should use for these approaches I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Which SQL database are you using? Do you have the option of storing the XML in a large string column or a native XML column? The tooling for deconstructing XML into separate relational data tables is not very good.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I do have the option to do that. Currently I am doing it by hand. I deserialized the xml onto a cs object that was auto generated using the xsd.exe program and I ran a database first procedure to generate my entities and db context. So I ended up mapping everything by hand